# Perforce: How do I sync the files in a specific subdirectory to a label

Tags: perforce

If I issue

```
p4 sync ...
```

it only syncs the files in my CWD and below to HEAD.

However, I am trying to sync a single directory to a label name

```
p4 sync @LABEL_NAME ...
```

and the result seems to be that the entire workspace (all files tagged with that label) is then sync'ed to that label, as though I had not added the "...".

Is this expected? And if so, how do I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@LABEL_NAME` is a "revision specification", while the `...` is a file pattern; what you want to do is to combine them, and specify both (the files in this directory and any sub-directories, at the revision in which they were tagged in the label).

To do that, you stick the revision specification after the file pattern, with no spaces between them:

`p4 sync ...@LABEL_NAME`

For more information about the things you can stick after the file pattern to refine your set of files, run:

`p4 help revisions`